# Choose to Insert Image as an Image or as a Comment

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which inserts images from the given path using specific set of numbers against which I already have an image database.

```
Sub InsertPics()
    Dim fPath As String, fName As String
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range
    Dim shpPic As Shape
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    fPath = "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\FY18-19\Images\"
    Set rng = Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)
    For Each r In rng
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    If r.Value <> "" Then
        Set shpPic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=fPath & r.Value & ".jpg", linktofile:=msoFalse, _
            savewithdocument:=msoTrue, Left:=Cells(r.Row, 2).Left, Top:=Cells(r.Row, 2).Top, Width:=-1, Height:=-1)
        With shpPic
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            If .Width > Columns(2).Width Then .Width = Columns(2).Width
            Rows(r.Row).RowHeight = .Height
        End With
    End If
    errHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description & ", " & r.Value
        On Error GoTo -1
    End If
    Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I need to do the below as well:

1. ask the file path
2. ask whether to insert the image as image or as a comment against those set of numbers and run accordingly
3. If the code can be converted into a select mode run, i.e. on a set of numbers I can run the code for (instead of the entire 'D'-Column I've embedded currently).

Answer (score 0):

May try this code and modify to your requirement.

```
Sub InsertPics()
    Dim fPath As String, fName As String
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range
    Dim shpPic As Shape, IsCmnt As VbMsgBoxResult


    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row)

    On Error GoTo Xexit
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select the range to import Images", "Import Image", rng.Address, , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = " Select Folder to Upload Images"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\user\DeskTop\"
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    fPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    fPath = fPath & "\"

    'Avoided further asking wheather all Images are to be uploaded as Comment
    'instead used bold font of the file names to do the same
    'try Next statement, if want all the images as comment
    'IsCmnt = MsgBox("Is the images to be uploaded as comments", vbYesNo)


  For Each r In rng
     If r.Value <> "" Then
        If Dir(fPath & r.Value & ".jpg") <> "" Then

            'If IsCmnt = vbYes Then    'try this branch if want all the images as comment
            If r.Font.Bold Then  ' instead of asking multiple times
            r.ClearComments
            r.AddComment ""
            r.Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture fPath & r.Value & ".jpg"
            Else
            Set shpPic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=fPath & r.Value & ".jpg", linktofile:=msoFalse, _
            savewithdocument:=msoTrue, Left:=Cells(r.Row, 2).Left, Top:=Cells(r.Row, 2).Top, Width:=-1, Height:=-1)
                With shpPic
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                If .Width > Columns(2).Width Then .Width = Columns(2).Width
                Rows(r.Row).RowHeight = .Height
            End With
            End If
        Else
        Debug.Print fPath & r.Value & ".jpg not found"
        End If
     End If
  Next r

Xexit:
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Code is tested with makeshift images. May disable `ScreenUpdating`as per actual condition.